# How to template specialize a function based on member variable existence

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Here is a simple example of what I want, but I don't know how to make the functions unambiguous. I am using echo to check the integrity of the type of the member variable for SFINAE and echo back void as the return type.

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    struct X {
        int x;
    };
    
    struct Y {
        int y;
    };
    
    template <typename V, typename... T>
    using echo = V;
    
    template <typename T>
    echo<void, decltype(std::declval<T>().x)> template_print(T& t) {
        std::cout << "x = " << t.x << std::endl;
    }
    
    template <typename T>
    echo<void, decltype(std::declval<T>().y)> template_print(T& t) {
        std::cout << "y = " << t.y << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    detail::X a{.x = 1};
    detail::Y b{.y = 2};
    detail::template_print(a);
    detail::template_print(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call this an issue of ambiguity, but of redefinition.

You can fix the issue you are having if you change the implementation of your `echo` alias template from "direct" to "indirect" as in the following snippet.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Echo
{
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
using echo = typename Echo<T, Ts...>::type;
```

Note that some may advise that you use `std::void_t`, but that would not work here either - for the exact same reason.

The issue is a bit complex, but you can avoid it by using an indirect alias template (like the one above that eventually resolves to the nested type) rather than a direct alias template.

At risk of shilling my own talk, the only place I've seen any sort of explanation of this is in the first part of this [CppCon 2021 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YC6_77-iEY).